# vertical align multiple rows with bootstrap 4 flexbox

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I am using bootstrap 4 flexbox and I have a full screen section in which i want two rows. One row in the middle of the section and one row at the bottom of the section. I made the flex container have flex direction: column.

If I have only one row its easy to center it with flexbox but when i add the second there is the problem. I use auto margins but its not completely as I want it. The more height the bottom row has the less centered the middle row is.

Here is a bootply to understand what i am asking. try to change the bottom row's height.

https://www.bootply.com/v9jmuxhLBd

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the ***Flexbox***, ***positioning*** and ***viewport units***:

```css
body {margin: 0}

div {width: 100%}

#section {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: Lavender;
}

#section .row:nth-child(2) { /* or: ":nth-of-type(2)" */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%; /* or "right: 0" */
}
```

```html
<header id="section">
  <div class="container-fluid h-100 text-white d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="row w-100 align-self-center justify-content-center" style="background-color: red">
      <div class="col-8 text-center" style="background-color: green">
      I'm vertically centered inside the #section!
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row w-100 align-self-center justify-content-center" style="background-color: red">
      <div class="col-8 text-center" style="background-color: blue">
      I'm just another row inside the #section!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully sure what you're trying to achieve here, if you want a three rows in that section then just have three rows like;

```
<header id="section">
 <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row"> <!-- opening row --> 
     <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">  <!-- or how ever you want it-->
    </div> <!-- closing row --> 
   <div class="row"> <!-- opening row --> 
     <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">  <!-- or how ever you want it-->
    </div> <!-- closing row -->  
   <div class="row"> <!-- opening row --> 
     <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">  <!-- or how ever you want it-->
    </div> <!-- closing row -->  
 </div> <!-- closing container --> 
</header> <!-- closing container -->
```

Comment: That's basic grid system. I want a row on the center of the screen(vertically alligned) and a row on the bottom of the screen

Comment: For the row at the centre of the screen you could use flex box to vertically align it centre (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hExwnLlj2xk) and for the row at the bottom of the page why don't you just put it into footer tags and at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: If you see the code, the middle is vertically centered with flexbox. My problem is that i cannot put the bottom row. I want the row at the bottom of the **full screen section** not at the bottom of the screen

Comment: I changed the question so you can understand and i also added a bootply.